# PyQt: application unexpectedly leaves main loop

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a simple PyQt application, which has a tray icon and can be hidden from taskbar by clicking close button or tray icon. Application can be closed from tray icon context menu. After user clicks "exit" in context menu, modal window with confirmation question appears . If user clicks "yes" application closes, if "no" application continues working.

When main window is hidden, application will be closed, even if user click "No" in modal window, but everything correct when window isn't hidden. This also happens with any modal window, for example with some information. I suppose the are some "magic" in parent paarmeter for QtGui.QMessageBox.question, but I don't know how to handle it. Please help to fix this annoying bug.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class SampleWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.init_ui()

        self.tray_icon.activated.connect(self.tray_click)
        self.show_window.triggered.connect(self.show_from_tray)
        self.now_button.triggered.connect(self.info)
        self.appexit.triggered.connect(self.app_close)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Message box')
        self.tray_icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray_icon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('clock.ico'))
        self.tray_icon.show()
        self.iconMenu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.show_window = self.iconMenu.addAction("MyApp")
        self.show_window.setDisabled(True)
        self.iconMenu.addSeparator()
        self.now_button = self.iconMenu.addAction("Now")
        self.appexit = self.iconMenu.addAction("Exit")
        self.tray_icon.setContextMenu(self.iconMenu)

    def info(self):
        now = str(datetime.now())
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Now', now)

    def app_close(self):
        info_msg = "Are you sure to quit?"
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                           'Exit',
                                           info_msg,
                                           QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes,
                                           QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            QtGui.QApplication.quit()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.hide_to_tray()
        event.ignore()

    def show_from_tray(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.showNormal()
        self.activateWindow()
        self.show_window.setDisabled(True)

    def hide_to_tray(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.show_window.setDisabled(False)

    def tray_click(self, reason):
        if reason != QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Context:
            if self.isHidden():
                self.show_from_tray()
            else:
                self.hide_to_tray()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sample = SampleWindow()
    sample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Qt application is terminated when the last window is closed. I'm not sure why it is closed after invoking context menu. I think it's because you hide your window in a strange way. Usually a window can be hidden using `hide()`.

This behavior can be easily disabled:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

Comment: It happens in my app too even if I do `hide()`. When main window is hidden and `QMessageBox` is dismissed, app closes itself, even ignoring `closeEvent` of the hidden window.